# frame_change_pre.append(handler) doesn't work

Tags: scripting

I wanna run a function each frame. So I create a new script and type in the following:

```
import bpy

def my_handler(scene):
    print("Frame Change", scene.frame_current)

print("test")
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

The problem is, that it simply doesn't work. When I hit "Run Script", "test" is written to the console, but nothing else happens then.

Comment: The hander "fires" when you change frames. What happens when you scrub frames or animate?

Comment: Oh, I thought it fires each frame of blender... can I do that somehow?

Comment: I found it: bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.append(my_handler)

Answer (score 2):

From link below: "By default handlers are freed when loading new files. In some cases you may want the handler to stay running across multiple files (when the handler is part of an add-on for example)."
You may need to use the persistent decorator:

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def my_handler(scene):
    print("Frame Change", scene.frame_current)

print("test")
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

see https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_60_6/bpy.app.handlers.html